# invalid base hashes in `extends` with 'include' -- gitlab-ci

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml

I have a huge .gitlab-ci.yml file that I am trying to turn into the "main" ci file by moving some parts to another files which will then be called with the use of the "include" keyword.

.gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: golang:latest

stages:
  - validate

include: /.gitlab/ci/_common.gitlab-ci.yml

validate:
  stage: validate
  extends: .gitlab-tf-backend
  before_script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform init -backend=false
    - mv $CI_PROJECT_DIR/deployment.zip .
  script:
    - terraform validate
    - terraform fmt -check=true
  only:
    - branches
```

.gitlab/ci/_common.gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
  GITLAB_API_ENDPOINT: https://gitlab.com/api/v4
  TF_ROOT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/terraform
  PLAN: plan.tfplan
  JSON_PLAN_FILE: tfplan.json
  GIT_DEPTH: 10

.gitlab-tf-backend: &gitlab-tf-backend
   - export TF_ADDRESS=${GITLAB_API_ENDPOINT}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${STATE_NAME}
   - export TF_HTTP_ADDRESS=${TF_ADDRESS}
   - export TF_HTTP_LOCK_ADDRESS=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock
   - export TF_HTTP_LOCK_METHOD=POST
   - export TF_HTTP_UNLOCK_ADDRESS=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock
   - export TF_HTTP_UNLOCK_METHOD=DELETE
   - export TF_HTTP_USERNAME=${USERNAME}
   - export TF_HTTP_PASSWORD=${GITLAB_TOKEN}
   - export TF_HTTP_RETRY_WAIT_MIN=5
   - echo "Using HTTP Backend at $TF_HTTP_ADDRESS"
   - terraform --version
   - terraform init
```

My file is correctly found by gitlab. It seems that my hidden job ".gitlab-tf-backend" is not recognized and cannot be called.

Full error is:

```
This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: validate: invalid base hashes in `extends` (.gitlab-tf-backend)
```

How could I properly call my '.gitlab-tf-backend' hidden job from my main .gitlab-ci.yml file ?

Comment: You're mixing YAML anchors and extend keyword, what you do would be of if your main script was including the hidden job with `script:\n<<: &gitlab-tf-backend. Now, make yourself a favor and use the gitlab-terraform image which takes care of all that for you. See [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/terraform_state.html#get-started-using-gitlab-ci) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Okay, found it.

It seems the .gitlab-ci.yml hidden job needs to have a "script:" to solve the problem. See below:

```
.gitlab-tf-backend: &gitlab-tf-backend
      script:
       - export TF_ADDRESS=${GITLAB_API_ENDPOINT}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${STATE_NAME}
       - export TF_HTTP_ADDRESS=${TF_ADDRESS}
       - export TF_HTTP_LOCK_ADDRESS=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock
       - export TF_HTTP_LOCK_METHOD=POST
       - export TF_HTTP_UNLOCK_ADDRESS=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock
       - export TF_HTTP_UNLOCK_METHOD=DELETE
       - export TF_HTTP_USERNAME=${USERNAME}
       - export TF_HTTP_PASSWORD=${GITLAB_TOKEN}
       - export TF_HTTP_RETRY_WAIT_MIN=5
       - echo "Using HTTP Backend at $TF_HTTP_ADDRESS"
       - terraform --version
       - terraform init
```